# Display String based in number value

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I'm using this `h:selectOneMenu` to set value into Database.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="role" value="#{profile.accountData.role}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="User" itemValue="0" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Developer" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sales" itemValue="2" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Administrator" itemValue="3" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Super user" itemValue="4" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

How I can display String into `h:outputText` based on int value which I set using `h:selectOneMenu`?

h:outputText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it will be to add some methods in your backend beans:

- Create a method which returns a `Map<Integer, String>` with the values to display in the `selectOneMenu`
- Initialize the `selectItem` values with a method which returns a `List<SelectItem>` from the previous `Map`
- Create a method which returns a `String` to retrieve an item name from an item value (Integer) by fetching in the map

Method to initialize the map

```
public Map<Integer, String> getMapOfItem() {
    Map<Integer, String> mapOfItem = new HashMap<>();

    // Initialize items
    mapOfItem.put(0, "User");
    mapOfItem.put(1, "Developer");
    mapOfItem.put(2, "Sales");
    mapOfItem.put(3, "Administrator");
    mapOfItem.put(4, "Super user");

    return mapOfItem;
}
```

Method to initialize the `selectItem` values

```
public List<SelectItem> getLstOfItem() {
    List<SelectItem> lstOfItem =  new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : getMapOfItem().entrySet()) {
        lstOfItem.add(new SelectItem(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }
    return lstOfItem;
}
```

Method to convert an `int` value to its corresponding label

```
public String itemName(int val) {
    return getMapOfItem().get(val);
}
```

In your JSF view, just call it like this (`bean` is your backend bean)

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="role" value="#{profile.accountData.role}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.lstOfItem}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and for the `h:outputText`

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.itemName(profile.accountData.role)}"/>
```

Hope it can help you